# What does the StarCraft 2 Collector's Edition Thor model look like compared to the regular one?

Tags: starcraft-2

I just heard that the Collector's Edition has a different Thor model than the regular edition. Does anyone know of a comparison shot of the two different models?

In this case I am talking about the Thor model inside StarCraft 2, not the Thor pet in World of Warcraft.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Regular" Thor :

[image: Thor]

"Super" Thor :

[image: Super Thor from Starcraft.wikia]

Comment: Looks similar to the Viking / Hel's Angels comparison. I'll bet it was originally conceived as a Thor mercenary, and then when it got cut, they decided to use the leftover asset as a CE bonus.

Comment: Just to let you know, 2 of your images here are dead.

Comment: Updated the post with the best image i could find. Had to add some useless characters because it didn't let me save otherwise because of too short body :-/